# Imprimir por consola una constante de otro archivo - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo en un archivo una constante

```js
const name = 'Erick'
```

Y en OTRO archivo, ejecuto

```js
console.log(name)
```

El navegador me devuelve

**Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined**

Pero si ejecuto el console.log en el mismo archivo, ahí si se muestra el valor de la variable.

El primer archivo lo trabajo con Gulp y babel y el segundo es un archivo cualquiera que llamo directamente desde el html.

// Edit
Los archivos son invocados de ésta manera por medio de pug

```html
script(src="js/sweetbox.js")
script(src="js/app.js")
```

Cuando abro la consola del navegador veo los archivos en ese orden, por lo que no se que está pasando. ¿Tendrá que ver con Babel o Browserify?

Comment: agrega a tu pregunta el código que nos muestre como los estás invocando

Comment: @Aprendiz Edité la publicación con más datos sobre el problema.

Comment: si esta en constante, intenta buscarlo en window.name

Comment: @JackNavaRow No entiendo muy bien lo de window.name, busqué en google y tiene que ver con algo distinto a lo que busco, si tienes algún ejemplo me ayudarías mucho. Pero si estoy trabajando con babelify, no se supone que esa constante se transforma en "var" para el navegador? Se debería poder acceder...

Comment: Deberías de leer sobre esto. Puede que tengas una mejor idea de lo que hace babel. Gulp es solo un task runner, solo eso; No lo confundas con babel https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JLee esto.avaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/export

Comment: @DiegoMolina Tengo entendido que babel compila el código para que lo entiendan los navegadores y Gulp es exactamente lo que dices. Con respecto a import y export, si funcionan bien pero en el caso de que programe una librería, quisiera que solo llamando a un método se inicialice, sin tener que usar import para usar mi librería.

Comment: Al declarar una constante, crear una variable en un determinado ámbito, por ende cuando intentas consumir dicha constante no está definida para el ámbito en la cual la consumes. `export` e `import` te ayudaría  para dicho problema.

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes es que no se ven entre ellos, tendrías que usar [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/export) en el archivo donde declaras la primera constante e [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import) en el fichero donde quieres consumirla.

De esta forma en tu archivo de origen tendrías:

```
export const foo = 'MY VARIABLE';
```

Y en el archivo del `console.log` importar `foo`

```
import {foo} from 'path-to-source-file.js'

console.log(foo);
```